# Ruby: 'gets' method called inside a method saves Nil instead of Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, terminal, gets

Ok guys, this in a Dungeon Text Adventure project that runs on terminal.

When user says he wants to "go north" it splits the string: first word checks for method and second word for parameter. That happens someplace else, i copy pasted the 2 methods that are giving me the following problem:

When it calls go(north) and north isn't a valid connection, it shows the options and asks user for direction again, the input the user enters at that moment is stored as Nil for some reason.

Why?? I also tried STDIN.gets.chomp.downcase! and had same Nil results

Here's the code:

```
    def find_room_in_direction(direction)

##-> if room connects with other on that direction, returns connection

        if find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).connections.include?(direction.to_sym)
            return find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).connections[direction.to_sym]

##-> if direction connection is not found, 
##-> show possible connections & return trigger to ask again inside go()

         elsif !find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).connections.include?(direction.to_sym)
             puts "I don't see any #{direction}..."
             puts "This room only connects #{(find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location)).connections.keys.join(', ')}"
             puts "Where should we go?"

             return :redo
         end
         end


    def go(direction)

        current_direction = @player.location
        new_direction = find_room_in_direction(direction)

##-> if REDO trigger received, ask for new direction & try again

        if new_direction == :redo
            puts "REDOING DIRECTION"

    ##-> HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
    ##-> this does ask for input

            new_direction = gets.chomp.downcase!

##-> but it saves Nil instead of the input, so that puts shows ''

            puts "#{new_direction}"

##-> so this call trows an error: cant call method to Nil

            new_direction = find_room_in_direction(new_direction)

##-> if user entered valid direction from start, the following would run 

        elsif new_direction != :redo && current_direction != new_direction
            @player.location = new_direction
            puts "You go #{direction},"
            puts "and enter #{show_current_description}"
        end
        end
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: This is hard to think about without consistent indentation, IMO. Comments belong at the level of the blocks they describe--and if you need comments for blocks, those blocks are probably better expressed as methods.

Comment: i wrote those comments to guide you while you read it (not for me) so you could understand it better, it doesnt help?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that your `elsif` condition will ever catch `new_direction` being `:redo` since that's your first `if` clause. That part of your expression can be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `downcase!` instead of `downcase`. `downcase!` changes a string in-place and returns nil if there were no changes (which is what is happening here).

```
str = "teSt"
puts str.downcase # test
puts str # teSt
str.downcase! 
puts str # test
```

See [the documentation for `downcase!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21)

Comment: jaja i was waiting on the timer, you're too fast

Answer (score 0):

Just bang chomp. As for downcase there are two variants - chomp and chomp!

Comment: its not storing any characters!

Comment: damn it. just de-bang downcase than. gets.chomp.downcase